# Modify Visual Studio's form designer code generator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I'd like to basically control the name of the method that the Visual Studio form designer uses for putting it's generated code in.  By default, this is named `InitializeComponent`.  But often times I need to have different layouts for different types of screen resolutions/aspect ratios (see [Designing forms to work on different resolutions and aspect ratios on Windows CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102631/designing-forms-to-work-on-different-resolutions-and-aspect-ratios-on-windows-ce) for more detail).  That way, at runtime I can choose how to layout the form by calling the appropriate one.

I realize that there is likely no trivial way to do this.  I assume I'll need to build a custom VS add-in and extend the existing forms designer and hook into the code generator and layout interpreter for this to work properly.  Any ideas on where I could start looking to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not switch within `InitializeComponent` and call different layout logic methods according to what platform you are?

```
if(platform.IsCE)
{
  CELayout();
}
else if (platform.Tablet)
{
  TabletLayout();
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could do that, however, since all of the code in the InitializeComponent method is generated I would still need a way to add that logic.